# How to use a hotel voucher on a charter trip?

Tags: hotels, accommodation, sweden

I and a friend decided to book a charter/package trip with flight, hotel and transfer included. I've only booked the cheap flight seats from these company for like 20€/return and this is my first package trip.

We choose "unspecified accommodation" and were sent a "hotel voucher" by email, which is in Swedish. I've not received any more details about the accommodation and I wonder how to redeem this voucher.

Searching the Swedish web and looking through various agencies FAQs didn't give me any answer.

*The agency is a small online one called Airtours, not the Thomas Cock one but a Swedish one with the same name.*

Comment: Is the problem that you don't understand the Swedish text on the voucher and need someone to translate it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.airtours.se/resevillkor/resevillkor-efter-augusti/

> Accommodation is advised upon arrival at the flight destination.

I see three options:

- The voucher is replaced with a voucher for the accommodation upon arrival at the flight destination
- The accommodation accept the generic voucher you have now
- Airtours make a paid reservation in your name at the accommodation

Side note: I would never book this myself. I read that cleaning might not be included and in some cases you must buy cleaning equipment yourself to clean the room before check out.

Answer (score 4):

What happened for us was this:

1. No information about what hotel we'd get before takeoff.
2. We found a guy at the airport holding a sign with the charter company's logo on it. He had a list of hotel rooms in different hotels and assigned us a room on the spot.
3. We went to the hotel and the receptionist asked for the voucher. I sent it to the hotel by email as they needed a copy to redeem.

The receptionist had a list of names with ours on it so we were expected.

---

As this was during low season we got a really nice room in a really nice hotel by the beach. There are horror stories out there of people with kids trying this during peak season.